# I have two Ubuntu boot entries, and when I try to remove one, it automatically comes back

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I'm currently dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu on a UEFI system. When I run: "sudo efibootmgr -v" the output is as follows:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0003,0004,0006,003A,0005,0000,0001,0038,0039
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,c2644bf2-33af-4372-a07a-52541287e412,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,c2644bf2-33af-4372-a07a-52541287e412,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...i................
Boot0002* P0: ST500LT012-9WS142 BBS(16,,0x0)AMBO
Boot0003* P4: PLDS DVD+/-RW DU-8A5HH        BBS(18,,0x0)AMBO
Boot0004* Atheros Boot Agent    BBS(20,,0x0)AMBO
Boot0005* UEFI OS   HD(1,GPT,c2644bf2-33af-4372-a07a-52541287e412,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)
Boot0006* P1: LITEONIT LMT-32L3M    BBS(21,,0x0)AMBO
Boot0038* UEFI: Network Card    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(7845c4c0516f,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.0:0<->0.0.0.0:0,0,0)AMBO
Boot0039* UEFI: Network Card    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(7845c4c0516f,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)AMBO
Boot003A* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,c2644bf2-33af-4372-a07a-52541287e412,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
Boot003B* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........o.P.L.D.S. .D.V.D.+./.-.R.W. .D.U.-.8.A.5.H.H....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.T.T.K.Y.5.0.0.5.1.8.C.2.4.B.1.D.A.K.1.0......AMBO
Boot003C* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........|.P.0.:. .S.T.5.0.0.L.T.0.1.2.-.9.W.S.1.4.2....................A..................1.N........>.;......@..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.P.0.:. .S.T.5.0.0.L.T.0.1.2.-.9.W.S.1.4.2......AMBOAMNO........~.P.1.:. .L.I.T.E.O.N.I.T. .L.M.T.-.3.2.L.3.M....................A..................1.N........>.;......B..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.P.1.:. .L.I.T.E.O.N.I.T. .L.M.T.-.3.2.L.3.M......AMBO
Boot003D* Network Card  BBS(Network,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........i.A.t.h.e.r.o.s. .B.o.o.t. .A.g.e.n.t.........................rN.D+..,.\...........:..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.A.t.h.e.r.o.s. .B.o.o.t. .A.g.e.n.t......AMBO
Boot003F* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........u.S.a.n.D.i.s.k. .C.r.u.z.e.r. .G.l.i.d.e. .1...2.7....................A.......................H..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.S.a.n.D.i.s.k. .C.r.u.z.e.r. .G.l.i.d.e. .1...2.7......AMBOAMNO........|.P.0.:. .S.T.5.0.0.L.T.0.1.2.-.9.W.S.1.4.2....................A..................1.N........>.;......@..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.P.0.:. .S.T.5.0.0.L.T.0.1.2.-.9.W.S.1.4.2......AMBOAMNO........~.P.1.:. .L.I.T.E.O.N.I.T. .L.M.T.-.3.2.L.3.M....................A..................1.N........>.;......B..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.P.1.:. .L.I.T.E.O.N.I.T. .L.M.T.-.3.2.L.3.M......AMBO
```

So there's currently two ubuntu options. I want to remove Boot003A, since that one is located at "/EFI/Ubuntu/grubx64.efi" when I believe it should be "/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi"

So I run "sudo efibootmgr -b 3A -B" and the output is as follows:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0003,0004,0006,0005,0000,0001,0038,0039
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0002* P0: ST500LT012-9WS142
Boot0003* P4: PLDS DVD+/-RW DU-8A5HH    
Boot0004* Atheros Boot Agent
Boot0005* UEFI OS
Boot0006* P1: LITEONIT LMT-32L3M
Boot0038* UEFI: Network Card 
Boot0039* UEFI: Network Card 
Boot003B* CD/DVD Drive 
Boot003C* Hard Drive 
Boot003D* Network Card 
Boot003F* Hard Drive
```

It looks like everything is okay. However, upon shutting down and booting up, the boot menu appears to be unchanged. When I run "sudo efibootmgr -v" the output is the same as it originally was. Any advice?

Comment: What machine is this?  Can you set a supervisor password, trust, etc. to see if that allows permanent changes?

Comment: @ubfan12 Do you mean like sudo privileges?

Comment: No, in the BIOS/UEFI settings.  Some machines allow more things when a supervisor password is used.  Acers (and others?) require settings trust on new bootloaders, maybe other things?

Comment: I have a Dell laptop. I haven't seen anything like that in my BIOS settings though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I actually resolved the problem. For some reason, the first ubuntu boot option was the one that I was able to delete. This was the one located at "/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi". Not sure why, since the cases don't line up, but at least it works now.